# console exits loop with incorrect value in C

Tags: c, while-loop

I have a function exits the loop when INCORRECT value is entered.

I want the function to ask the user to enter the correct value BEFORE it exits the loop.

I am passing the value of `hours` entered by the user into the function `wrongHours`

if the user is to enter hours below 0 or above 23, the function should ask the user to enter something again, but it just goes to the next line? am I missing a flag or something?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

// function prototypes
int wrongHours(int n);


int main(void)
{

    int hours;
    int minutes;

    printf("Enter the first hour value (0 - 23): ");
    scanf("%d", &hours);

    while (wrongHours(hours)) {

        printf("Enter the first hour value (0 - 23): ");
        scanf("%d", &hours);
    }

    printf("\nEnter the first minute value (0 - 59): ");
    scanf("%d", &minutes);


    _getch();
    return 0;

} // end main

// function validates that hours are between 0 - 23
int wrongHours(int n) {
    int i;

        if (n < 0 || n > 23) {
            printf("Invalid data entered, try again!");
            return 0;
        }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It skips it because the while loop is set to 0 on an incorrect hour, therefore it never executes what's inside. Try switching your `wrongHour` returns.

Comment: In `wrongHours` why do you have a loop? Isn't all you want to do is check that the value of `n` is between `0` and `23`? That only requires a single line.

Comment: You need to consume the `'\n'` after your `scanf`

Answer (score 2):

I dont know why you want to use for loop , below is some formatted code , please check if it satisfy your need

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

// function prototypes
int wrongHours(int n);

int main(void)
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;

    printf("Enter the first hour value (0 - 23): ");
    scanf("%d", &hours);

    while( wrongHours(hours)) {
        printf("Enter the first hour value (0 - 23): ");
        scanf("%d", &hours);
    }

    printf("\nEnter the first minute value (0 - 59): ");
    scanf("%d", &minutes);

   _getch();
    return 0;
} // end main

// function validates that hours are between 0 - 23
int wrongHours(int n) 
{
    if (n < 0 || n > 23) {
        printf("Invalid data entered, try again!");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could mak the first loop a `do...while` loop to avoid code duplication

Comment: *below is some formatted code*, umm. . the indentation is completely off! And it is not a "paste code in SO" issue.

Comment: Please consider editing your answer, adding an explanation of what went wrong and the details of your fix.

Comment: That is the most inconsistently *formatted code* I've ever seen. Do yourself a favor and learn to *properly and consistently* format your code.